# Understanding Kohonen SOM visualisation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to understand (and implement) how to visualize nodes in SOM. If I train it on some high-dimensional data, the only thing i can do is calculate distance between nodes in high dimensional space. I would like to plot some nice scatter-plot or even grid, but how?

Comment: what kind of data do you have ? Maybe you can use (could have used) PCA to reduce its dimensionality for viewing